# Background Video overlapping button

Tags: html, css

So I have a very simple html that makes a video a background video and an audio that plays. Now when I try to add a button, it gets created, but the video overlaps it. How do I fix this? I asked my friend and he said make the buttons z-index higher than the videos in css, but it didnt fix the issue.

**HTML:**

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Doffy</title>
    
    <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
        <source src="/images/doffy.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <button type="button" id="myButton"> New music</button>
    <audio  id="BackgroundM" hidden="true">
      <source src=""  type="audio/mp3" id="source">
    </audio>
    <script src="/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
#myVideo {
    position:fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  
  #myButton {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 2;
  }
```

Comment: So you want the button to display on top of the video, or beneath it?

Answer (score 0):

```css
#myButton {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative; // <<-- Add this
  }
```

`z-index` only works in positioned elements:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Answer (score -1):

change your video z-index in negative such as -2 and try

Comment: That won't do anything (for the reasons explained in Eric's answer from last year).